# rails with vuejs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, ruby, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

for the past 6 months we struggling with a issue in loading our app page in local development.
we getting blank pages with net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) in the console logs.
after a few refresh the page loads.
this is very faustring.

our development is: Rails 5.0.7.2 + vuejs 2 with webpack webpacker@4.2.0.

can it be solved? thank you!

**package.json**

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "^10.#",
    "yarn": "^1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "vue": "2.#.#",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.#.#",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./bin/webpack-dev-server",
  },
```

**webpacker.yml**

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  webpack_compile_output: true
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  public_root_path: public

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: ['app/assets']
  compile: false

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: false

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 3040
    public: 0.0.0.0:3040
    hmr: true
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'

test:
  <<: *default

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs

testing:
  <<: *default

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs

staging:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true

app:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: false
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `rm -rf public/packs` to delete `/packs`, and then restart the webpack dev server `bin/webpacker-dev-server`. I think it would be fine.

---

I think it's just inconsistency of the compiles files which I ran into several times.

You can check the `[project root]/public/packs`. I guess it would be very possible for the files the browser requesting are not there. In more details, the entry points in `[project root]/public/packs/manifest.json` is not consistent with the files in the same folder.

```json
"entrypoints": {
  "desktop": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/desktop-7547483.....js" // it cannot find this file in the folder
      ],
   // ...
}
```

Removing them all and compiling them again is the easiest way to solve that.

Comment: i already tired that, it will help for a couple of refreshes and then it will be again 404.